# How can I add key values into a dictionary from reading in each line of a .txt file and update values?

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to python so I'm trying pick it up. If I had a `.txt` file like this:

```
A B
A C
A E
B D
C D
C F
D G
F C
G H
```

And I read in the `.txt` file line by line with:

```
with open(txtFile) as file:
                for line in file:
```

I want it so that if the letter doesnt exist, then create it but if it does, itll add the letter it connects to, onto that existing letter. How would I be able to create a dictionary that maps everything so it ends up looking like this:

```
graph = {
        'A': ['B', 'C', 'E'],
        'B': ['D'],
        'C': ['D', 'F'],
        'D': ['G'],
        'F': ['C'],
        'G': ['H']
        }
```

This is basically all I have right now:

```
graph = {}

        with open(txtFile) as file:
                for line in file:
                        line.split()

        graph.append
```

I dont know how to actually add keys into the dictionary. But I guess once the keys are in I can just use something like:

```
graph['A'].append(line[1])
```

right? Also, would I have to use a snippet of code that traverses all the keys in the dictionary in order to see if that key already exists? Or will duplicates just not work?

Comment: Which part are you confused about? Reading a file? Creating a dictionary?

Comment: Well, I'd write some more code for a start. What you have there is the absolute bare minimum required to open a file and iterate through it - and even then its syntactically incorrect. That won't build a dictionary.

Comment: I guess, my problem is I dont really understand how to append to a dictionary in Python, and what happens if a value I append already exists

Comment: Well I have some code, I just think its kindda crappy so I didn't upload it. Lemme put it up real quick.

Comment: I added the little snippet of code I have and added more specifications in my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You are on the right track, try using `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested code):

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(list)

with open(txtFile) as file:
    for line in file:
        s_line = line.split()
        graph[s_line[0]].append(s_line[1])
```

Comment: Woah, thats really cool. In Python, you can set multiple variables to an element.split() and it will store the splits into the respective variables?(k,v) What if there are more splits then variables, does it just save the amount that exists? Or return an error

Comment: @Thaddius, my main goal was to show the `defaultdict`.

Comment: This is perfect, learned quite a few things from this alone. Thanks so much